# runghc very slow (17-33 Seconds just for Printing an Array)

Tags: haskell, ghc

At my university i currently have a Lecture about Haskell. Now i got a Job to make a Program. We got this Sample File:
https://pastebin.com/6wPdEgHZ

Starting from that, we have to develop the Program around it. The Functions simulate a Database-Access.

Since i dont like programming in WinHugs, i set up Visual Studio Code with GHC. I added a main-Function to print out Function-Outputs. It looks like this:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = print artikel
```

i added that to the top. Thats it. At first i wanted to output the Articles. That are the runghc-Outputs:

```
[Running] runghc "c:\Users\5CG949285X\Documents\DHBW\5_Semester\Funktionale Programmierung\restaurant.hs"
[(1,"Hamburger","Hauptgericht",8.0,6.0),(2,"Cheeseburger","Hauptgericht",9.0,6.5),(3,"Chickenburger","Hauptgericht",8.5,6.5),(4,"Pommes frites","Beilage",3.0,2.0),(5,"Wedges","Beilage",3.5,2.0),(6,"Cola","Getraenk",2.5,1.0),(7,"Eistee","Getraenk",2.0,1.0),(8,"Wasser","Getraenk",1.5,0.5)]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 24.527 seconds

[Running] runghc "c:\Users\5CG949285X\Documents\DHBW\5_Semester\Funktionale Programmierung\restaurant.hs"
[(1,"Hamburger","Hauptgericht",8.0,6.0),(2,"Cheeseburger","Hauptgericht",9.0,6.5),(3,"Chickenburger","Hauptgericht",8.5,6.5),(4,"Pommes frites","Beilage",3.0,2.0),(5,"Wedges","Beilage",3.5,2.0),(6,"Cola","Getraenk",2.5,1.0),(7,"Eistee","Getraenk",2.0,1.0),(8,"Wasser","Getraenk",1.5,0.5)]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 30.182 seconds
```

As u see, it takes very long. Is it just cause the file has VERY much code in it? Or did i do something wrong setting it up?

Comment: Yes, it’s probably because of the amount of code in the file. (You can confirm that by replacing the long list with an empty one.) Having so much data embedded as Haskell isn’t ideal; maybe you can ask your professor for a version that reads from a file instead.

Comment: Also `runghc` is one of the slowest ways to run a program, which surely exacerbates the problem. Who knows, maybe it would be tolerably fast if you compiled it before running it.

Comment: I do remember GHC being very slow on compiling long lists in the far past. I don't know if this improved. You could either put the data in a file and load it, or isolating the list in a separate Haskell module, compiling it once, and develop the rest of the program so to avoid recompiling that list every time.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if the interpretation overhead explains such abysmal performance. It's just not *that* much work. How long does it take to compile? If that takes a while, you should file a GHC bug report. The developers take compile time performance seriously.

Comment: Wait, what? Why are people saying it makes sense? It doesn't make sense. "So much data" and "long list" -- the entire file is 700 bytes after deleting comments, that is *tiny*. And I can't reproduce it -- here `runghc` takes 0.1s on that file. There is something really wrong with your setup.

Comment: @DanielWagner: See the “raw” version on Pastebin. Several hundred thousand tokens. The syntax-highlighted version is cut off for whatever reason.

Comment: @Ry- Ah, WOW! That seems like a bug in pastebin that the non-raw format silently omits so much content. (Even if it's going to omit long lines, to avoid trying to show binary data or similar, it should *say* it's done so.)

Comment: It's also simply a pretty bad idea to put such a lot of data in a source file, for multiple reasons. Better store it external as e.g. Yaml and either load that file normally at runtime, or use [`file-embed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/file-embed-0.0.15.0/docs/Data-FileEmbed.html) to get the data into your executable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If i let the file as it is, just put `module Restaurant where` on the top and add a second file, called "Main.hs" in the same directory, which looks as follows:

```
module Main where

import Restaurant

main :: IO ()
main = print artikel
```

it runs much faster.

If i run that Main.hs it looks like this:

```
[Running] runghc "c:\Users\5CG949285X\Documents\DHBW\5_Semester\Funktionale Programmierung\Main.hs"
[(1,"Hamburger","Hauptgericht",8.0,6.0),(2,"Cheeseburger","Hauptgericht",9.0,6.5),(3,"Chickenburger","Hauptgericht",8.5,6.5),(4,"Pommes frites","Beilage",3.0,2.0),(5,"Wedges","Beilage",3.5,2.0),(6,"Cola","Getraenk",2.5,1.0),(7,"Eistee","Getraenk",2.0,1.0),(8,"Wasser","Getraenk",1.5,0.5)]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.473 seconds

[Running] runghc "c:\Users\5CG949285X\Documents\DHBW\5_Semester\Funktionale Programmierung\Main.hs"
[(1,"Hamburger","Hauptgericht",8.0,6.0),(2,"Cheeseburger","Hauptgericht",9.0,6.5),(3,"Chickenburger","Hauptgericht",8.5,6.5),(4,"Pommes frites","Beilage",3.0,2.0),(5,"Wedges","Beilage",3.5,2.0),(6,"Cola","Getraenk",2.5,1.0),(7,"Eistee","Getraenk",2.0,1.0),(8,"Wasser","Getraenk",1.5,0.5)]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.434 seconds

[Running] runghc "c:\Users\5CG949285X\Documents\DHBW\5_Semester\Funktionale Programmierung\Main.hs"
[(1,"Hamburger","Hauptgericht",8.0,6.0),(2,"Cheeseburger","Hauptgericht",9.0,6.5),(3,"Chickenburger","Hauptgericht",8.5,6.5),(4,"Pommes frites","Beilage",3.0,2.0),(5,"Wedges","Beilage",3.5,2.0),(6,"Cola","Getraenk",2.5,1.0),(7,"Eistee","Getraenk",2.0,1.0),(8,"Wasser","Getraenk",1.5,0.5)]

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.487 seconds
```

So MUCH faster and actually workable with. In the End, the Requirement was to deliver just a Single .hs File, that works in WinHugs. So i think i will keep working in my Main.hs now and consolidate it back to the original File, once im finished. Should work.

Thanks @all